Object from AppBar that overlaps body in Scaffold - Flutter Website
I'm creating website with flutter. I want to have AppBar with object(I'm trying with image) that stick out of this AppBar and overlaping small part of scrollable body. I wan't AppBar to remain always on top.
enter image description here
I've tried to put image in AppBar but image is being cut where the AppBar ends. I don't know how to make image sticks out of AppBar. So I've decided to create custom AppBar using Stack instead of AppBar widget. But I don't know how to combine custom AppBar made of Stack and scrollable body under this AppBar in Scaffold body parameter. And make body scrollable, ale as scrollable widgets don't work with stack.
Scaffold with scrollable container 1
Scaffold with scrollable container 2

So in general I need to create AppBar with image bounded to it and
this image should sticks out of the AppBar and overlap scrollable
body part.

Maximum scrolled to top
Maximum scrolled to bottom
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 200.0, vertical: 5),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 700,
                    height: 700,
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Container 1',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 200.0, vertical: 5),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    width: 700,
                    height: 700,
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Container 1',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  height: 140,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 250,
                          ),
                          const CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 60,
                            backgroundImage:
                                AssetImage('images/monster_logo.jpg'),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 30,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                              width: 180,
                              child: RichText(
                                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                text: TextSpan(
                                  text: 'MONSTER GARAGE MOBILNY MECHANIK',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
                                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize: 30,
                                      height: 0.8,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                softWrap: true,
                              )),
                          const SizedBox(width: 80),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              'O nas',
                              style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 50),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              'Cennik',
                              style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 50),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              'Usługi',
                              style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 50),
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Text(
                              'Kontakt',
                              style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
                                  color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 80),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                              minimumSize: const Size(150, 50),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                              children: [
                                const Icon(Icons.call,
                                    color: Colors.white, size: 20),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Zadzwoń',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.bebasNeue(
                                      fontSize: 20, letterSpacing: 1),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const Positioned(
                top: 100,
                left: 700,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/pobrane.png'),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
